# how to start a service when your sreen is locked in android?

Tags: android

i am making an application which displays floating window that contains contact name from your device(if saved) else shows an unknown number, it works fine when the screen is on but after locking thee phone, the floating window does not appear on the phone when there is an incoming call, i have to unlock the phone to see the floating window, can someone help me with this?

Comment: Please update the post with what you have tried so far

Comment: if you want background processing, work manager is a good way to start. Don't know about displaying a UI tho.